# App domain boundries when sub-applications share common app pool in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool

I know that main/top-level applications in IIS are bound by app domain, even if sharing a common application pool. However, what if the app contains several sub-applications, some of which share the same app pool as the parent (don't ask me why, but this is what I've been dealt).

Because a main/top level app exists, how will boundries be affected is sub-applications are under it? In the example below, most of these parent/child applications share the same application pool.

Specifically, I need to use a static property in the same namespace (DLL) for each of the child applications and am worried about any access to this from multiple applications. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that putting an application in a separate application pool can avoid various potential problems. The disadvantage is that one process per application pool, and more applications will easily consume memory.

When the parent/child applications share an application pool, memory pressure can be reduced, and due to the good design of the application pool, the isolation between applications is very high, and there will be no mutual influence problems. But if something goes wrong and a chain reaction occurs, all applications may crash and throw an exception.